# Rotation in OpenGl ES to place objects then rotate the world

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, augmented-reality

I am developing an augmented reality application for android and trying to use openGl to place cubes at locations in the world. My current method can be seen in the code below:

```
     for(Marker ma: ARData.getMarkerlist().values()) {

        Log.d("populating", "");
        gl.glPushMatrix();



        Location maLoc = new Location("loc");
        maLoc.setLatitude(ma.lat);
        maLoc.setLongitude(ma.lng);
        maLoc.setAltitude(ma.alt);

        float distance = currentLoc.distanceTo(maLoc);
        float bearing = currentLoc.bearingTo(maLoc);
        Log.d("distance", String.valueOf(distance));
        Log.d("bearing", String.valueOf(bearing));
        gl.glRotatef(bearing,0,0,1);
        gl.glTranslatef(0,0,-distance);
        ma.cube.draw(gl);          

        gl.glPopMatrix();
    }

    gl.glRotatef(y, 0, 1, 0);
    gl.glRotatef(x, 1, 0, 0);`
```

Where y is yaw and x is the pitch. currently I am getting a single cube on the screen at a 45 degree angle someway in the distance. It looks like I am getting sensible bearing and distance values. Could it have something to do with the phones orientation?  If you need more code let me know.

**EDIT:** I updated bearing rotation to `gl.glRotatef(bearing,0,1,0);` I am now getting my cubes mapped horizontally along the screen at different depths. Still no movement using heading and pitch but @Mirkules has identified some reasons why that might be.

**EDIT 2:** I am now attempting to place the cubes by rotating the matrix by the difference in angle between heading and bearing to a marker. However, all I get is a sort of jittering where the cubes appear to be rendered in a new position and then jump back to there old position. Code as above except for the following:

```
        float angleDiff = bearing - y;
        gl.glRotatef((angleDiff),0,1,0);
        gl.glTranslatef(0,0,-distance);
```

*bearing* and *y* are both normalised to a 0 - 360 scale. Also, I moveed my "camera rotation" to above the code where I set the markers.

**EDIT 3:** I have heading working now using, `float angleDiff = (bearing + y)/2;`. However, I cant seem to get pitch working. I have attempted to use `gl.glRotatef(-x,1,0,0);` but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky to tell exactly what you're trying to do here, but there are a few things that stick out as potential problems.

Firstly, your final two rotations don't seem to actually apply to anything. If these are supposed to represent a movement of the world or camera (which mostly amounts to much the same thing) then they need to happen *before* drawing anything.

Then your rotations themselves perhaps won't entirely do what you intend.

Your cube is rotated around the Z axis. The usual convention in GL is for the camera to look down the Z axis, with the Y axis being considered 'up'. You can naturally interpret axes however you like, but a rotation around 'Z' would not typically be 'bearing', but 'roll'. 'Bearing' to me would be analogous to 'yaw'.

As you translate along the Z axis, I assume you are trying to position the object by rotating and translating, but obviously if the rotation is around the same axis as you translate along, it won't actually alter the position of the cube - it will always just be directly in front of the camera, spinning on its axis.

I'm not really clear on why you're trying to position the cube like that when it seems like you start off with a more specific location. You could probably directly construct a more appropriate matrix.

Finally, your camera/world rotation is two concatenated rotations around Y and X. You call these pitch and roll, but typically using euler angles for a camera rotation does not result in an intuitive result where terms like pitch and roll make complete sense. It is common to maintain an orientation and apply individual rotations to that in order to update it, rather than attempting to update several dependent rotations.

So yes, I would expect that this code, in the absence of other matrix operations, would likely result in drawing one or more cubes straight ahead which are simply rotated by some angle around the view direction.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will try and use some of your observations to fix my code and report back. The reason I am using bearing and distance is because I couldn't think of a better way to convert between latitude/longitude to a (x,y,z) coordinate system used by openGl.

Comment: Also, it might be worth noting that I am getting heading. yaw and roll from a fused sensor I created using accel, magnetometer and gyro. I can get the rotation matrix from this fused sensor but I have not been able to get results from that either.